# probability of both balls of same color

Tags: probability

Boxes 1 and 2 contain 4 white, 3 red and 3 blue balls; and 5 white, 4 red and 3 blue balls respectively. If one ball is drawn at random from each box, what is the probability that both the balls are of the same colour?

Comment: Hi. Can you show a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is easier to help you!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it colour by colour.

$Pr($Both same colour)

$=Pr($both white$)+Pr($both red$)+Pr($both blue$)$

$=Pr($White from 1$)Pr($White from 2$)+Pr($Red from 1$)Pr($Red from 2$)+Pr($Blue from 1$)Pr(Blue from 2)$

and the rest should be easy.

Note: Used additive property of events, and the multiplicative property of independent events.